# Multiple commands in one custom keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

How do I add multiple commands to one shortcut?
Adding something like

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 0 0 && xdotool getactivewindow windowsize 50% 50%
```

doesn't work, but either command in isolation works. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script that does the same thing and assign it to the custom shortcut. For instance, `~/.local/bin/my_script`:

```
#!/bin/sh
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 0 0
xdotool getactivewindow windowsize 50% 50%
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but is this desired behavior? I can't think of a reason why the keyboard shortcut menu only accepts one command.

Comment: It is a custom command so I don't think there is a shell call. That is, the command is not parsed by a shell that would be able to tell that you want two separate commands separated by && but as a single command with the rest of the line as its arguments…